# `scipy.signal.peak_widths` unexpected behavior when peak value is at index 0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I use `scipy` in order to estimate the FWHM value of some distributions I have. Each distribution is represented by a list.

I use `scipy.signal.peak_widths` to estimate the FWHM by defining this custom function:

```
def find_fwhm(vector_data):
    vector_data = np.array(vector_data)
    
    # Find the peaks
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(vector_data)

    # Edge case
    if np.argmax(vector_data) ==0:
        peaks = np.concatenate(([0], peaks))

    peak_values = vector_data[peaks]

    # Find index of highest peak (max)
    highest_peak_index = np.argmax(peak_values)
    highest_peak_value = peak_values[highest_peak_index]
    highest_peak_index_original_data = peaks[highest_peak_index]

    # Find FHWM
    results = peak_widths(vector_data, peaks=[highest_peak_index_original_data], rel_height=0.5)

    return results[0][0]
```

I have to add an `if` for some edge cases where the max peak is at index 0 if the input vector. However, this returns FWHM equal to 0 however I would expect to return a value between 0 and 1.

Here is a toy example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_widths

# build fake vector
vector = [0.05] * 60
vector[0]=0.5
vector[1]=0.2

# plot
plt.plot(vector, '-o')
plt.axhline(max(vector)/2)
plt.show()

fwhm = find_fwhm(vector)
print(fwhm)
#0
```

In the plot we see that the Half Maximum is between index 0 and 1, so shouldn't the function return a value between 0 and 1 since it uses interpolation?

[image]